# Linux not recognizing MacBook Pro in target disk mode connected over Thunderbolt

Tags: linux

I'm running kernel 4.17.4, on top of Ubuntu 18.04.  I have a MacBook Pro, booted into Target Disk Mode (so it should appear as an external drive to a connected Thunderbolt machine) connected to the Thunderbolt 3 port.  I compiled and ran the tbtadm program, since that was suggested in another thread.  However, it returns no devices attached, yet an Apple Macintosh device appears in the topology, as below:

```
Controller 0
├─ Details:
│   ├─ Name: Kerberos_DA, HP
│   └─ Security level: SL1 (user)
│
└─ Macintosh, Apple, Inc.
    └─ Details:
        ├─ Route-string: 0-1
        └─ UUID: 8236c78a-d2cc-0b51-95bc-dc4e8fe6891b
```

How do I get the MacBook to be recognized and appear as a disk?

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not have a way for it to be recognised as an external disk.

From High Sierra onwards, Apple has been using Apple File System (APFS) for which there are no Linux drivers yet.

> Apple File System (APFS) is a proprietary file system for macOS High
>   Sierra and later, iOS 10.3 and later, tvOS 10.2 and later,[6] and
>   watchOS 3.2 and later,[7] developed and deployed by Apple Inc.[8][9]
>   It aims to fix core problems of HFS+ (also called Mac OS Extended),
>   APFS's predecessor on these operating systems. Apple File System is
>   optimized for flash and solid-state drive storage.

A possible solution is creating an intermediate FAT partition for data exchange. It *might* work. Otherwise you need another Mac with at least High Sierra for being able to access that data.

Thunderbolt is also not particularly well supported in Linux.

Comment: Even if the disk was formatted APFS, wouldn't it still appear as a disk under Linux, and be assigned a file in /dev, even if it couldn't be mounted?

Comment: I figured it out:  Apparently, Target Disk mode doesn't actually present itself as a Thunderbolt disk, rather it presents itself as a "targetdm" device, which Linux doesn't seem to have drivers for.